# How can I generate dynamic urls in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

In my application I am currently using the standard parameter passing, for example
http://localhost/api/shops/deals/$shop_id

But i need the urls to be like 
http://localhost/api/shops/$shop_id/deals

How can I achieve that?

Comment: shops() is your function, pass parameters to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `application/config/routes.php` file to do that. Like

```
$route['api/shops/(:num)/deals'] = 'api/shops/deals/$1';
```

Now when your URL will be `http://localhost/api/shops/3/deals` then it will execute as `http://localhost/api/shops/deals/3`

for more details https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: @AbhishekSharma Thanks. enjoy your day